# Make csv file available for download which is generated by a python script

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

Python script runs on click of button using ajax.The script generates a csv which i want to show to the user so that it could be downloaded.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes).

Comment: How can i give url of the file to the <a> tag? As Django always gives error that no such directory exist.File is in the main directory and html is in the subfolder template.How should i proceed

Answer (score 0):

One way would be for the python code to save the csv file with a unique filename (perhaps generated by some combination of the date and the user's name) in the "static" directory and then create a link string (as either a relative or absolute URL) with that filename to use something like this:

`<a href="{{ csv_filename }}" download>Click here to download CSV file</a>`

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp for a clear explanation and demo of the download attribute of the  element.

You might need to mess with file permissions, but I think Django can serve a file from a static directory to a user client without any extra fuss. You probably also want to purge the CSV files older than some reasonable period. CRON could do that, or it could be part of a startup routine.

Comment: Thanks Todd but I still have a small query.For eg->The python script is creating a file  with unique name and saving on file system.Now how can i give its url bcz when i give filename it gives error as shown below(csv file stored in root directory):  
localhost/extract_friends/1st-degree_2019-04-07_1107.csv
Using the URLconf defined in fbextractor.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
extract_friends/ what [name='my_view']
extract_friends/ [name='index']
The current path, extract_friends/1st-degree_2019-04-07_1107.csv, didn't match any of these.

Comment: I think you should be saving the CSV file within the directory structure of your Django project. If your python code then adds the path of that directory to the filename it generates, Django will go straight to that directory without trying any of its default paths. I suggested the "static" directory, but using localhost in a URL will be referring to the localhost of the client's system, not yours. The surest thing would be to use an absolute path to the file, something like `http://yoursite.com/static/some_directory/yourCSVfile.csv`